# okay...im getting a scripting error when trying to port a map from a game to blender

Tags: python, animation, scripting, import

[image]

I'm getting an error stating,

"

Error: Python:   File "\Text", line 9
base_dir ="G:\umodel\game\assets"
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \uXXXX escape  "

i cant exactly remember what im doing wrong...i havent done this in quite sometime.

Comment: Backslashes are treated as escape characters in Python strings. Either use forward slashes for paths (`'C:/blah'`) or use raw strings (`r'C:\blah'`).